# Why does DateTime to Unix time use a double instead of an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, floating-point, unix-timestamp

I'm needing to convert a DateTime to a Unix timestamp. So I [googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=datetime+unix+.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) it looking for some example code

In just about all the results I see, they use `double` as the return for such a function, even when explicitly using `floor` to convert it to an integer. Unix timestamps are always integers. So what problem is there with using either `long` or `int` instead of double?

```
static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan diff = date - origin;
    return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: IMHO just not to validate the input date. It should return a long or an ad-hoc struct

Comment: There is no reason, it is just crummy code.  Cast to a long, it can't overflow.

Comment: I'll add that by definition the Unix timepstamp is UTC.  The method should check if the DateTime.Kind is UTC, Local, or Unspecified.  At minimum if Local I would convert to UTC before performing the conversion.  Optionally, if you want a Unix timestamp that is local you could add an overload or parameter to not perform the conversion to UTC.

Comment: @Nate, hmm yea true, but it doesn't matter in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, I would implement it with an unsigned long instead of requiring the user to round up or down and cast to an int or long.  One reason someone might want a double is if a structure similar to timeval were being used such as in [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).  It allows for sub-second precision...

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the [2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) bug on 32 bit systems?

Comment: One would think they could just have used a long though.

Comment: @nos possibly. I suspect more systems support float64 natively than int64. Additionally maybe some was interested in fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Doubles cover more ground then any other variable in the int type.

Comment: yes, but a `long` would cover thousands of years. Surely my software won't be running in a couple thousand years.

Comment: I suppose if you had some software that needed to calculate something eons into the future or the past, it may help.  That's a special case though, and one would probably use a custom data type under said scenario.

Answer (score -4):

It's not a question of "years". but of hours on a reasonable machine (s), properly linked.

But can you imagine collating the enormous storage? I have about 30TB off data and it swamps me - I spend more time cataloging than actual work.

Good luck in your endeavors